# Problems with ionic build

Tags: angular, ionic4

I am learning ionic and have the following problem when write command

`ionic build`

I want to generate the folder **www**

https://github.com/jquishpe/imagenionic/blob/master/error1.png

```
C:\Personal\ionic\platzi-music>ionic build
> ng.cmd run app:build
Generating ES5 bundles for differential loading...
An unhandled exception occurred: Call retries were exceeded
See "C:\Users\HITSS\AppData\Local\Temp\ng-sOfQFc\angular-errors.log" for further details.
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess ng.

        ng.cmd run app:build exited with exit code 127.

        Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more information.
```

`ionic build --verbose`

https://github.com/jquishpe/imagenionic/blob/master/error2.png

File Content C:\Users\HITSS\AppData\Local\Temp\ng-sOfQFc\angular-errors.log

```
[error] Error: Call retries were exceeded
    at ChildProcessWorker.initialize (C:\Personal\ionic\platzi-music\node_modules\jest-worker\build\workers\ChildProcessWorker.js:193:21)
    at ChildProcessWorker.onExit (C:\Personal\ionic\platzi-music\node_modules\jest-worker\build\workers\ChildProcessWorker.js:263:12)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:203:13)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:272:12)
```

Any ideas to solve the problem.
Thanks in advance.

Versions programs:

> Angular CLI: 8.3.21
>
> Node: 12.8.0
>
> npm: 6.10.2
>
> Windows 10 Pro 64 bits

Comment: I think the command to be used should be something like this: "ionic cordova build <platform>" this should probably work

Comment: I try "ionic cordova build android"
https://github.com/jquishpe/imagenionic/blob/master/error3.png

I get the same error

Comment: Hey is ionic serve working fine??

Comment: @Akshay Sure the "ionic serve" works fine

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Go to tsconfig.json in your project and search for 'target' attribute and then change its value  to 'es5'`

Comment: Thank you waleed Jubeh. I had value "target": "es2015". and change it "target": "es5". It work fine.